# Aws amplify shows much less data then in dynamodb exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I have following problem. In my amplify studio i see 10k datapoints

[image]

But if i take a closer look into the corresponding database i see this:

[image]

I have over 200k+ data but it shows only 10k inside amplify studio. Why is it like that?

When i try this code in my frontend:

```
let p = await DataStore.query(Datapoint, Predicates.ALL, {
        limit: 1000000000,
      })
console.log(p.length)
```

I get `10000` back. The same number like in amplify studio.

Other questions: Whats the best way to store dozens of datapoints? I need it for chart visualizing.

Comment: I'm not experienced with AWS amplify at all so hopefully other folks can contribute but you may be hitting the 10k resolver limit for GraphQL? Might be completely wrong however

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary well, i checked it 1 hour ago, it went up to 18k now. Really strange. Where can i find those limits?

Comment: So it’s not that - I haven’t worked with AppSynx sorry!

Answer (score 0):

A DynamoDB `Query` or `Scan` request does not return all items in one huge list. Instead, it returns just a single "page" of results, whose size defaults to 1MB. A client library like amplify could call these `Query` or `Scan` requests repeatedly to collect all pages into one huge array in memory, but that doesn't make too much sense once it grows very big. So applications usually want to iterate over all the results, not to collect them into one huge array in memory.

So most DynamoDB APIs provide a **pagination** interface for the query and scan operations - which provides you with one page of results, and a way to get the next page. Alternatively, some APIs can give you an iterator over results - and internally do this pagination. I'm not familiar with Amplify so I don't know which API to recommend. But certainly an API that returns all results as one big array must have its limits, and apparently you've found them.

Comment: I was thinking to use aws timeSeries for huge amount of data. Is this an idea?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can definitely have huge partitions in DynamoDB (like a time series) - in some cases you are limited to 10GB (when you have LSI) but in other cases not even that is a limit. Querying the entire partition is definitely possible - you just need to do it in 1MB pages, not all at once. Your client probably doesn't even have enough memory to store all the results in one huge array.